# Goes through a fast infinite loop

Tags: javascript, animation

I was trying to create an animation box that'll move like this - onclick of start button, to the right, then bottom, left and top. On click of stop button, it stops moving, no matter what it is, and then picks back up when clicked on start again.

I managed to get it working when it was just left to right and then right to left, but when I trying to create the whole loop (left->right->bottom->right->top), I'm facing problems. What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
 var pos = 0; 
 var pos1 = 0;
 var s = document.getElementById("start");
 var st= document.getElementById("stop");
 s.addEventListener("click",btstart);
 st.addEventListener("click",btstop);
 var t, t1; /*t and t1 should be global variables so they can be accessed by the btstop function*/
function btstart(){
    var box = document.getElementById('box');
    t = setInterval(movel, 10);
 }

function movel() {
    if(pos >= 150) {
         t = setInterval(moveb, 50);
    }
    else {
        pos += 1;
        box.style.left = pos+'px';
    }
}

function moveb(){
    if (pos1 >= 150)
    {
        t = setInterval(mover, 50);
    }
    else {
        pos1 += 1;
        box.style.top = pos1+'px';
    }
}
function mover() {
     if(pos === 0) {
         t = setInterval(movet, 50); /*Note: clearing t, not t1. Ends the function/script completely*/
    }
    else {
         pos -= 1;
        box.style.right = pos+'px';
    }
}
function movet(){
    if (pos1 === 0)
    {
        t = setInterval(movel, 50);
    }
    else {
        pos1 -= 1;
        box.style.bottom = pos1+'px';
    }
}

function btstop() {
    clearInterval(t);
    /*clearInterval(t1);*/
}
/*var box = document.getElementById("box");*/
```

Comment: Then show us your code and where the problem is

Comment: Just added the code. I'm new here, I accidentally clicked on post before pasting the code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code a little bit clearer. I only use one interval that will check for the current position and then use `setAndMove` to move the box and save the position

```js
var box = document.getElementById("box");
var startButton = document.getElementById("start");
var stopButton = document.getElementById("stop");
startButton.addEventListener("click", start);
stopButton.addEventListener("click", stop);

var interval;
var horizontal = 0;
var vertical = 0;
var space = 50;

function start() {
  interval = setInterval(function() {
    if (horizontal === 0 && vertical === 0) {
      //box is top left
      setAndMove(space, 0, 'left', space);
    } else if (horizontal === space && vertical === 0) {
      //box is top right
      setAndMove(space,space, 'top', space);
    } else if (horizontal === space && vertical === space){
      //box is bottom right
      setAndMove(0,space, 'left', 0);
    } else if( horizontal === 0 && vertical === space){
    //box is bottom left
      setAndMove(0,0, 'top', 0);
    }
  }, 1000);
}

function stop() {
  clearInterval(interval);
}

function setAndMove(hori, vert, direction, directionValue){
  horizontal = hori;
  vertical = vert;
  box.style[direction] = directionValue + "px";
}
```

```css
#box {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  position: fixed;
}
#start{
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>

<button id="start">Start</button>
<button id="stop">Stop</button>
```